# Angular - Wrong package versions?

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, npm-package, npm-version

I've an angular app.
In the package.json I defined for all angular packages the version 12.2.9 like:

```
"@angular/animations": "^12.2.9",
"@angular/cdk": "^12.2.9",
"@angular/common": "^12.2.9",
"@angular/compiler": "^12.2.9",
"@angular/core": "^12.2.9",
...
```

I deleted the `node_modules` folder and the 'package-lock.json`

The I installed all packages with `npm install`

After that, calling `npm outdated`, the current version for all my angular packages is 12.2.13 and not 12.2.9

Where is defined, that the 12.2.13 version is installed and not the version from the `package.json`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `package-lock.json` there is all information about your installed packages in `node_modules`. if you go there and search the file for `@angular/animations` for instance you will see your version.

Solution is to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and clear cache by running `npm cache clean --force`.

#### UPDATE:

---

As [Harun Yilmaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331040/harun-yilmaz) mentioned in comments:

> There are carets (^) in the versions. So, deleting package-lock.json and node_modules and running npm install will still install the latest compatible version.

You can find out what exactly `^` and `~` do in npm package managing in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json) by [jgillich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/941764/jgillich).

Comment: Please note that there are carets (`^`) in the versions. So, deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and running `npm install` will still install the latest compatible version.

Comment: Yeah you're right  I forgot to mention that. I will update.

Comment: Ah ok - I thought the (^) is only for npm update.